# how to see whitespace chars in svn diff?

Tags: svn, diff

```
 $svn diff my.object 
 -        <description>reverse reference to the Update Center Enrollment Application task.
 +        <description>reverse reference to the Update Center Enrollment Application task.
```

It must be a white space/hidden char or a end of line problem.... but how do I figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out a simple work around

`svn diff my.object > foo.txt`

then use:

`od -c foo.txt`

It shows the new line chars, and I found one had `\n` and the other had `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Just pipe output to preferred program. E.g.

> $ svn diff my.object | od -c

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party diff program. `svn diff` has a `--diff-cmd` parameter that allows you to use a tool such as [gvimdiff](http://www.vim.org/index.php) which is what I use.

I have a rather simple script that takes the parameters SVN passes into third party diff programs, and shows me where the diffs are.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# mydiff

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant DIFF => qw(mvim -d -f);

my $parameters = $#ARGV;
my $file1 = $ARGV[$parameters - 1];
my $file2 = $ARGV[$parameters];
my $title1 = $ARGV[$parameters - 4];
my $title2 = $ARGV[$parameters - 2];

$ENV{TITLE} = "$title1  -   $title2";
system DIFF, '-c', 'let &titlestring=$TITLE', $file1, $file2;
```

If I need to use it:

```
$ svn diff --diff-cmd mydiff
```

And, I'll see something like this:

[image]

You can see line #158 has white space difference. With GVIM, you can also filter out white spaces in the diff too -- just like most diff programs.

Comment: I guess... If you `:set list`, you will see tab characters and `$` marking EOL, so you can see extra white space at the end of a line. If you have `:set fileformat=unix`, you will see `^M` at the end of the line if there's a Windows EOL character at the end. Keep in mind I just happen to use GVIM. You can use almost any ***program*** editor (vs. a mere text editor) and get similar results.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable approach could be:

```bash
svn diff myfile --diff-cmd colordiff | less -R
```

It somehow only worked when using [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/colordiff.html).